# Zend_Form int validation..?

Tags: zend-framework, zend-form

In the Zend Framework is there a standard validator for an input that I want to be numbers only? Its the age field in my registration form so I obviously only want numbers.

Something like addValidator('NumbersOnly');

Thanks

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can use the Digits validator class

```
addValidator('Digits')
```